# textarea maxlength attribute not counting special characters immediately

Tags: javascript, angularjs, textarea, special-characters, maxlength

Below is a piece of code, which gives a text area and restricts the no. of characters in it:

```
<textarea ng-model="someText" placeholder="Type..." maxlength="10"></textarea>
<span class="counter">{{10-someText.length}}</span>
```

It does not reflect the remaining charecters, upon typing space or enter unless I enter a normal character.

For Example,
when I type **a** It shows 9 (as expected)

when I type **a** and then two **spaces**, it will show 9 (special characters not counted immediately)

when I type **a** and two **spaces** and **b**, it will show  6 (as expected)

How do I get the proper no. of remaining characters?

Comment: Did you try my solution? Got any other problem? Let me know.

Comment: Thank you  AndreaM16. Your solution works well. Now it is counting the special characters. Sorry for the delay in replay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use **ng-trim="false"** in order to count line breaks, spaces and special characters. Try like that:

```
<textarea ng-model="someText" placeholder="Type..." maxlength="10" ng-trim="false">
</textarea>
  <span class="counter">{{10 - someText.length}} still remaining!</span>
```

- [Ng-Input Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/input/input%5Btext%5D)
- [Ng-Input Directive Documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)
- [Working JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9ns3tcb/)

I hope I've been helpful.

Comment: The Fiddle works fine in Firefox, but not in chrome. When I press Enter key, chrome counts it as 2 characters but mozilla counts it as 1.

Comment: That's really weird, I'll try to check that when I'll be at home.